# What does the JavaScript [+num] syntax do?

Tags: javascript

I have come across a refernce to a JavaScript syntax that I don't understand and cannot find any references to online.

```
[+num]
```

What does this syntax do and when is it used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It forces a conversion to a number.

```
  +'0'; // 0
  +[]; // 0
  +true; // 1
  +false; // 0
  +"I'm Not A Number"; // NaN
```

From Operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2b_(Unary_Plus)

> **+ (Unary Plus)**
>
> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
>   already. For example, y = +x takes the value of x and assigns that to
>   y; that is, if x were 3, y would get the value 3 and x would retain
>   the value 3; but if x were the string "3", y would also get the value
>   3. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary
>   plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a
>   number, because it does not perform any other operations on the
>   number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats,
>   as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in
>   both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
>   Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
>   parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

Comment: And here's the reference for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2b_(Unary_Plus)

Comment: And don't forget that the "non-obvious" ones turn into `NaN`, e.g. `+'abc'`, `+({})`, `+(function(){})`, etc.

Comment: @maerics NaN is ironically enough of the type `number`, so it's still a conversion to a number :) But yes, that's an important observation to be aware of :) I think the OP is asking about the square brackets too, in which case it creates an array with one element containing the number.

Comment: @PaulPRO: right, just adding to his examples, since the next question for many people might be "well what about objects?" =)

Comment: @maerics Yup, that didn't come out the way I wanted at first. I really just wanted to point out the irony that NaN (not a number) is a number, haha. I like doing that ;)

Comment: @PaulPRO: ha ha, yeah.  Is it a number or not a number?  It's both!